# How to map active record class specific attribute to corresponding general purpose concern methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, activesupport-concern

I have a concern in my rails app that goal is to convert a label to a date range. Basically I have a string date_label which takes a value like "tomorrow" that helps compute two date fields like date_end and date_end which are actual dates. The concepts date_label, date_start, date_end are the "common concern concepts" but they need to be mapped to the corresponding active record fields that have specific names in the active record class in which the concern is included.

Here is the concern code so far :

```
module DateSchedulable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    before_save :compute_date_range
  end

  LABEL_TO_DATE_RANGE =  {
    'asap': { start: Date.today, end: Date.today },
    'same-day': { start: Date.today, end: Date.today },
    'next-day': { start: Date.tomorrow, end: Date.tomorrow },
    'two-day': { start: Date.today, end: Date.today + 2.days },
    'seven-day': { start: Date.today, end: Date.today + 7.days }
  }

  def compute_date_range
    if self.date_label_changed?
      date_range = get_date_label_range(self.date_label)
      self.date_start = date_range[:start]
      self.date_end = date_range[:end]
    end
  end

  def get_date_label_range(date_label)
    if LABEL_TO_DATE_RANGE[date_label.to_sym]
      LABEL_TO_DATE_RANGE[date_label.to_sym]
    elsif Date.is_parseable?(date_label)
      date = Date.parse(date_label)
      { start: date, end: date }
    else
      { start: nil, end: nil }
    end
  end
end
```

Im especially concerned about how to handle this `date_label_changed?` in `compute_date_range`.

I need, for instance, to include this concern in the class `HelpList` which has the following active record attributes `"default_requested_date_label", "default_requested_date_start","default_requested_date_end"`. I need to ensure the mapping between my class specific attribute names and my general concern concepts. Ideally I would maybe like to writte something like :

```
class HelpList
  include DateSchedulable
  date_label :default_requested_date_label
  date_start :default_requested_date_start
  date_end   :default_requested_date_end
end
```

But Im really open to suggestion and would like to know if there is an elegant way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You should really start again and reconsider your approach  completely as Ruby actually has [ranges](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-last) which are built for this very purpose:

```
DATE_RANGES =  {
  asap: Date.today..Date.today,
  same_day: Date.today.begininng_of_day..Date.today.begininng_of_day,
  next_day: Date.tomorrow.begininng_of_day..Date.tomorrow.end_of_day,
  two_day: Date.today.advance(days: 2).beginning_of_day..Date.today.advance(days: 2).beginning_of_day,
  seven_day: Date.today..Date.today.advance(days: 7)
}
```

ActiveRecord will create BETWEEN queries when you pass a range to `.where`:

```
tricenarians = User.where(birth_day: 30.years.ago...40.years.ago)
# SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.birth_day BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

If you are using Postgres it actually has [native timestamp and date range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html) so you can store the range in a single column. Otherwise you can get the bounds with `Range#begin` and `Range#end`.

Don't fall in the temptation of using the user friedly labels as hash keys. Either use the I18n module or `String#dasherize`. Strongly coupling the two is a mistake since just updating the label presented to users will break any reference in your code.

> I need to ensure the mapping between my class specific attribute names
>   and my general concern concepts.

You can make your module configurable by creating a class method and saving the names of the columns in [class instance variables](https://www.codegram.com/blog/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby/) or by dynamically creating methods.

```
module DateSchedulable
  # ...
  class_methods do 
    def date_label(attribute_name)
      class_eval do
        @_date_label_attribute = attribute_name
      end
      # or
      class_eval do
        define_singleton_method :date_label_attribute do
          attribute_name
        end
      end
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

This kind of metaprogramming is how Rails builds stuff like callbacks, validations and associations. Be sure you read up the mixin pattern because you're going to need a good understanding of Ruby flavor OOP.